# Hibernate Search: predicate with multiple IDs from the IndexedEmbedded (similar to .id())

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to find a way so that I can make the following use case work: Author is embedded in the Book (that is indexed), and I save the IDs of the Author in the book (author.id). I have a list of Author IDs that I would like to search for.

Is the best way to do this using .terms()? Or is there any better way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the best way to do this using .terms()?

Yes.

```java
List<Long> myIds = List.of( 1L, 2L );
List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.terms().field( "authors.id" )
                .matchingAny( myIds ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Here's the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-terms

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation, was just wondering if I have missed something, or if there is a better way of doing it. Anyways thanks for the answer, and for the awesome work at Hibernate Search!